# Finding overlap and sum of rasters using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, mosaic

I have about 300 rasters that I need to find the overlap and sum of to find 'hotspots'. I set each raster value to 1 and used the Mosaic to New Raster tool to create a new raster. I tested this with two files (test), the test raster has a value of 2 where the other two rasters overlapped.

How do I manage to find all the overlapping rasters and add them together in ModelBuilder?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Cell Statistics tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) :

> Calculates a per-cell statistic from multiple rasters.
>
> The available statistics are Majority, Maximum, Mean, Median, Minimum,
>   Minority, Range, Standard deviation, Sum, and Variety.

Use the SUM statistic and ensure `Ignore NoData` is ticked and set the output extent environment to Union of inputs

Comment: Unfortunately through model builder, it did not add together the rasters that overlapped, the value is still equal to 1.

Comment: Did you use the SUM statistic and ensure `Ignore NoData` is ticked?

Comment: Yes I did, it seems like the output is the exact same as the input rasters

Comment: Weird, I just did this yesterday with 800 rasters. Do the rasters all have the same extent?

Comment: No they don't have the same extent, I put up another photos of where are my rasters are located on the map. I need to figure out if they over lap, and if they do, then add the rasters together.

Comment: Set the output extent environment to Union of inputs

Comment: I am sorry, where do I find this output extent environment in the model builder?

Comment: In the cell statistics tool, not the model http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/setting-environments-for-a-model-process.htm